# Is it possible for Ned to die if there's no one else around?

Tags: pushing-daisies

*Pushing Daisies* is about Ned, a piemaker, who has the ability to bring back the dead with a single touch. But, if he keeps them alive for longer than one minute, someone else has to die in their place.

If Ned were to bring someone back to life for longer than a minute, and he and the person he brought back are the only two people in the area, would it be possible for Ned to die in that person's place?

If so, what would happen to all the people, animals, etc. that Ned brought back to life? Would they continue living or would they all die, too? (Note: I only just finished season one.)

Comment: The rule is not that it has to be a PERSON that takes their place. Any living being will do. Even insects qualify. I remember a scene with bees; we find Ned learned this early on in boarding school. It is unlikely Ned would ever be found to be insufficiently covered.

Comment: I've noticed that it seems that each life has a different exchange, if you will. When he brought back those frogs when he was at school, several birds died. When he revived the rotten fruit for his pies, flowers died. When he brought back a human being, another human died. When he revives an animal, a human doesn't die, nor does a plant, but another animal.

Comment: I guess you paid closer attention.